# Creating simple layered PSD file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, photoshop

I'm making a tiny imaging tool in C# .Net 3.0.

I want to make a psd file putting some images in layers.

I googled but found not that useful informations.

photoshop SDK may be only for photoshop plugin or automating.

However, as I see the iPad App, Recreate, has psd export feature so there must be a way to create psd file in code.

Is there some libraries or the other way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any library that you could use but the [PSD file format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm#50577409_pgfId-1036097) has been released by Adobe. Perhaps you could write your own methods to create the PSD.